How are trials allocated to the different brackets in hyperband in Optuna?
In the original hyperband implementation, defining the minimum and maximum resources, automatically defined the number of configurations to examine.
In Optuna, that is not the case. The number of configurations to examine is limited by the parameter n_trials in the study.optimize function.
So if we set the following:
study = optuna.create_study(
    
    pruner=optuna.pruners.HyperbandPruner(
        min_resource=1,
        max_resource=81,
        reduction_factor=3,
    ),    
)

study.optimize(
    objective, 
    n_trials=50,
)

There will be 50 configurations examined.
We can examine the number of brackets (rounds of successive halving) like this: study.pruner._n_brackets.
And we can examine the budget allocated to each initial configuration in each round like this: study.pruner._trial_allocation_budgets.
My questions are:

How are the 50 n_trials specified in study.optimize allocated to each bracket?
How can I identify a bracket in the result? The result being the study variable.

